# Why Sqflite is very slow on Android?

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

I have developed a flutter app for android and for Ios, both with the same code. I followed the official guides to implement the database with sqflite. The problem comes when I have to work with my database (inserts, deletes...). My app has to do about 12 inserts, that are instant on IOS devices, but take about 10 seconds on different average Android devices. Both are realese versions.

As I don't have prior experience with databases I don't know if it's normal to take that long or what is going on here. As I mentioned the code is the same for Ios and for Android, I use the function insert(), about 12 of them, and the data I insert is quite simple.

```
await db.insert(data);
await db.insert(data);
await db.insert(data); 
...
```

In addition to my problem I found the same problem here https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/202 , but nothing more.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not that Sqflite is particularly slow it is because you are using `await` with multiple `db.insert`. Basically `await` is a thread-blocking process which means that your 2nd `db.insert` won't be performed until the 1st one is done, same goes for the 3rd one it won't be completed while the 2nd is still running.

Moreover you are chaining calls to `db.insert`, instead you should use `db.batch()` it will allows you to plan and perform your `db.insert` all at once without blocking your database and avoid ping-pong between native code as it is said in the [package documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#batch-support).

Here is a code sample of how you could do your insertions:

```dart
final batch = db.batch();

batch.insert('myTable', data);
batch.insert('myTable', data);
batch.insert('myTable', data);

await batch.commit();
```

Just by doing this you will only need one `await` which should improve your performances.